# Whitelabel Error Page There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). null identifier

Tags: sql, spring, view, model, null

I am trying to do a practice Spring boot program with JpaRepository. I have code for a web app that allows users to register. A user registers and and it adds the login credentials to a database.  I have another web page view where you can update the user address info.  The problem is when you update the user address, the web browers shows

**Whitelabel Error Page**:

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Jun 08 12:13:08 EDT 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
null identifier
```

I have the code displayed on here.

https://github.com/jkirkish/Assignment13.git

Any help with the error on the web browser when I update the address information after hitting the update button would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1. First Issue - You have not specified the action in **users.html** :

```
<div th:if="${#lists.size(users) == 1}">
    <form action="" method="post">
```

This line should be replaced to :

```
<form th:action="@{/users/{userId}(userId=${user.userId})}" method="post">
```

2. Second Issue I see is with `Address` Entity. Try correcting below:

- Adding Strategy to the `Id` field (userId)
- Remove `@MapsId` annotation.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}


@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
```

Comment: I will put that line of code in the form action and see what the results are.

Comment: ok so I changed the code in the users HTML file to what was stated above

Comment: this is the error I am getting:                                                                                                                  021-06-08 21:28:22.192 ERROR 20736 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier] with root cause

Comment: If I try to update the user address from the user.html view I get the same white page internal server error. If I use the MySQL WorkBench to go to the database with users and addresses.  I can insert the address information there no problem.  I then restart my application and see it popup on the user.html view and edit it just fine.

Comment: The java console prints out the lines of code that shows the error in processing the application.  I copied and pasted the strack trace on the README file in the Github repository.  I read that I am getting an org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier.  Not sure where it is occuring in the code. Or why it is occurring nor how to fix that.

Comment: @JosephKirkish : Updated the answer . Please try. Hope this answers your question.  please answer the question if it is resolved.

Comment: I think I got it